# JavaFX not working on DrJava

Tags: java, javafx, drjava

I am trying to get to know and work with JavaFX using the DrJava IDE. However I cannot run any of the programs. I tried running the Hello World example, I receive the following error: `Static Error: Undefined Class HelloWorld`. It will compile and everything, but just will not run. Anyone know why?

Comment: its a bug http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/bugs/948/

Comment: @Reimeus So I will just need to use another IDE?

Comment: This appears to be a long-standing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you ever got your answer, but for anyone coming here wanting to use JavaFX in DrJava:

Download JavaFX: [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io)

Remember where you downloaded it to

Open DrJava

Open preferences under the Edit tab in the top left

In the resource locations category, [click add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U6t6.png)

Enter the JavaFX SDK folder and go to [lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJbWp.png)

From there highlight every .jar file, press select and apply!